# problem creating a select using enum values

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

i have mysql table and has a data like this

i have a table with two columns value and label and both the columns have the enum type

Data of value is:

```
-43200|-39600|-36000|-32400|-28800|-25200|-21600|-18000|-14400|-10800|-7200|-3600|0|3600|7200|10800|14400|18000|21600|25200|28800|32400|36000|39600|43200|46800
```

Data of Label is:

```
GMT-12:00|GMT-11:00|GMT-10:00|GMT-09:00|GMT-08:00|GMT-07:00|GMT-06:00|GMT-05:00|GMT-04:00|GMT-03:00|GMT-02:00|GMT-01:00|GMT|GMT+01:00|GMT+02:00|GMT+03:00|GMT+04:00|GMT+05:00|GMT+06:00|GMT+07:00|GMT+08:00|GMT+09:00|GMT+10:00|GMT+11:00|GMT+12:00|GMT+13:00
```

but as  i have two columns one is for the value and other is for the label, how can i create a function which will create a select having a option value and text and create a dropdown,

if its a single column, i could have done a `valuelist` of `valuearray` and loop over it, but now its two columns, i am bit confused how to

any clue

Comment: Do you have control of the query and what it outputs?

Comment: i can control the query

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the query? And is the "create a select having..." the dropdown box? (just making sure you aren't referring to the query) Or is the data contained all as the two lists from the query?

Answer (score 2):

You already know how to do this, you're just not thinking about it in context.

1. Two columns, two lists (or arrays).
2. You know you can loop over "a" list to create HTML.
3. So loop over BOTH lists to create HTML.

Reference each list item by position and you're good to go.

```
<cfset sValuesList = "-43200|-39600|-36000|etc.">

<cfset sLabelsList = "GMT-12:00|GMT-11:00|GMT-10:00|etc.">

<cfoutput>
    <select>
        <cfif listLen(sValuesList, "|") EQ listLen(sLabelsList, "|")>
            <cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(sValuesList, "|")#" index="x">
                <option value="#listGetAt(sValuesList, x, "|")#">
                    #listGetAt(sLabelsList, x, "|")#
                </option>
            </cfloop>
        </cfif>
    </select>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: this is excellent, my only question: how can i store the selected value like i was thinking of this `43200|-39600|-36000::0`, so `::0` is the selected value and same on the label as: `::GMT`